# lynx can I stop it splitting urls?

Tags: lynx

I'm using lynx to dump a website.

```
lynx -dump https://URL.com > file.txt
```

Some URL's are split onto 2 lines and I would like to stop that if possible. Do I have any options?

I run a sed command that removes lines not starting with http, so you can see the problem.

Thanks,
Chris

Edit: I should add that the links I want do not get put in the visible or hidden link sections.

Comment: I'd like a solution that simply prevents lynx from breaking the lines/urls, but still use the normal width when formatting text normally.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. Just needed to set a wider width using "-width="